# Cannot fetch values from Json with no key in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

```
[
    {
        "Id": 52,
        "Name": "name1",
        "author": "john"
    },
    {
        "Id": 53,
        "Name": "name2",
        "author": "jacob"
    },
    {
        "Id": 54,
        "Name": "name3",
        "author": "jobin"
    }
]
```

I used the following code to fetch and parse this json array with no main key

```
SBJsonParser *parser1 = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
   NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str2]];
    // Perform request and get JSON back as a NSData object
    NSData *response1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request1 returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSError *error;
   NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response1 options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

but i am getting the following exception

```
data parameter is nil
```

this exception is occuring at this code

```
NSData *response1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request1 returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

How to iterate the id value?

Comment: check if you are getting any error in NSError variable...

Comment: are you getting response in `jsonArray` ?

Comment: there is no need of `main key` to access elements? you can easily access elements.

Comment: no error only exception as mentioned above, please tell me how to access elements

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of JSON files here, so i would:

```
NSArray *jsonArray = ; //your JSON

for (NSDictionary *dict in jsonArray) {
    NSInteger number = [dict[@"Id"] intValue];
    NSString *name = dict[@"Name"];
    NSString *author = dict[@"author"];
}
```

Comment: the exception is occuring at this line `NSData *response1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request1 returningResponse:nil error:nil];` so how can i fetch values?

Comment: Make sure the URL is correct, are you performing the correct HTTP request type (GET)?

Comment: I'd recommend AFNetworking or MKNetworkKit, to streamline these things

Answer (score 0):

What you given is perfect it is working for me try check your API
And you did not use the SBJson also try print the NSLog("%@",jsonArray);

Answer (score 0):

The return value from sendSynchronousRequest is void. So it makes sense that the data parameter is nil.

```
+ (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                      queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue
          completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *response,
                                      NSData *data,
                                      NSError *connectionError))handler
```

The data value you're expecting is provided in the block. That's where you want to extract the NSArray and do something with it.

In my current project, I'm not using synchronousRequest but doing something similar. Maybe that helps you.

```
    NSError *error;
    // Read the given JSON file from the server
    NSData *filedata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    if (filedata)
    {
        // Read the returned NSData from the server to an NSDictionary object
        // Essentially this is the bookstore in NSDictionary format.
        NSArray *bookStore = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:filedata options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    }
```